# stop webbrowser before navigation starts in c#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a `webbrowser` and link-click detection function

user clicks on a link and based on `href` attribute the link detector decides to navigate or not but the `webbrowser` open the link anyway

Is there any way to stop the navigation to a clicked link?

I already used `webbrowser.Stop()` but it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Continue?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
    { 
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Of course, instead of a MessageBox, you can use your own logic to decide on whether or not to continue.